# Unable to see full pop-up on mobile

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I have added the code from MailChimp for subscription pop-up, and it's working fine on desktop, but on mobile, it's just showing the cross button and everything else is hidden. When I rotate the mobile and rotate again, then I can see the pop-up. I don't know why

I just have an image on the front-end and the MailChimp code in the header.

MailChimp Code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us20.list-manage.com","uuid":"22c2d7662403df9b1dcd37f96","lid":"a5970e3ec6","uniqueMethods":true}) })</script>
</head>
```

HTML

```
<body>

  <img src="homepage.png" width="100%">

</body>
```

I can only see the cross button on mobile instead of the pop-up. The website is : http://badmaash.store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The issue is with how MailChimp determines the height of your elements.

On load of the page, the script calculates the `height` of the banner incorrectly (always 0). In addition to the `height`, the `margin` (24px) is then added, which is then set to the `iframe` as a style.

A quick fix is to use CSS to override the `height` applied by MailChimp to allow the banner to appear correctly.

```
<style>
    .mc-layout__bannerContent iframe { height: auto !important }
    // Remainder of your CSS
</style>
```

---

#### Detailed Answer:

On load of the page, JavaScript is executed to determine the height of the content (`.bannerContent`) of the iframe:

[image]

This value (`24px`, which is the calculated `height` (0) + `margin-bottom` (24) at the time of calculation) is then applied to the `iframe`, seen here:

[image]

When the script is fired to show the modal, you only see the toolbar because of the defined height on the iframe.

Removing the height of the iframe will show all content, as seen here:

[image]

(The reason rotation works is because a `resize` handler is called, correctly applying the height of the content to the iframe.)

I was able to address this fix by using Charles to re-write your HTML and inject the following CSS: `<style>.mc-layout__bannerContent iframe { height: auto !important }`.

[image]

Here's the end result:

[image]

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to upvote or comment on [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253479/jack)'s answer but I wanted to say thanks.

I've been searching high and low for an answer on this issue and his answer is definitely correct.

I'm using WordPress and added his code between my `<head></head>` tags in the html. Not sure if it's the best solution but it works.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

  <script> /* MailChimp script here */ </script>

  <style>
    .mc-layout__bannerContent iframe { height: auto !important }
  </style>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```